# Xfce4 + Xfwm middle click Title bar closes window - how to remove action?

Tags: xfce, mouse, window-manager, window-title

I just need to remove ANY middle click action on every window Title bar in my Xfce4 environment. Just need to make a middle click do nothing when clicking on the title bar.

p.s. I'n using Xfwm

Comment: That's odd. A middle click on title bar only sends the window to behind other windows; It will not close the window itself. Or, do you mean "how to remove action of middle click on taskbar buttons"?